# Fastest way to fill a business object with a datareader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, datareader

What is the fastest, best & recommended way to fill a business object by using a datareader in DAL ? Currently I use

```
myObject.Name=(string) myDataReader["Name"];
myObject.Age=(int) myDataReader["Age"];
```

Damien.

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve, there are allot of ways to get data from date database and fill an object. Can you provide a bit more information?

Comment: Hi I want to fill and return DTO's inside a single database class file & I don't want to create a separate fill method for each object I'm working on using IDataRecord.

Comment: The fastest, in this case, will almost certainly not be the best...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question (instead of recommending an ORM), the **fastest** way is what you have already illustrated with the couple of lines of code. Those lines are quite brittle code, but if you eliminate DbNull checks and TryParse or Parse operations, and use column ordinals instead of column names, then the code can't get much faster or more direct.

Of course if you are going to take this approach then you had better make sure that your database code is absolutely bulletproof and returns items in exactly the right order, with values that are appropriate (i.e. no null values in columns that will be assigned to value types back in the C# code). Needless to say this sort of code is not very maintainable long term...

Comment: Thank you slugster that was really helpful, nulls will be handled at query level.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) project as a lightweight ORM implementation.

It was actually developed by (and for) StatOverflow as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using data reader then your way is the good way apart from the fact that you can use null checking for columns that could be null. The fastest way would be the one that uses column indices instead of names. The best way would be to create a T4 template that would operate on some data-dictionary (perhaps xml file) to generate fastest code for both DTO and to fill those DTO.

Edit: Oh! - I forgot - the recommended way would be to use some O/R mapper framework and do not worry too much about such mundane details!

Answer (score 1):

[Entity Framework and ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) are your friends.

If you want to tweak it later on, learn T4 and write your own templates, you can write stuff like:

- Standart CRUD WCF web services
- Cloning
- etc.